# Problem with compile static QT with static openssl [MSVC]

Tags: qt, build, openssl

I am trying to build Qt 5.12.3 (MSVC) statically with linking static openssl.

I started the cmd from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`

then i run the below command to setup the needed PATH,

`vcvars32`

then navigate to the QT Src and started the command:

```
configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc -prefix out -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sqlite -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -openssl-linked -I E:\Qt\OpenSSL-Win32_full\include -L E:\Qt\OpenSSL-Win32_full\lib\VC\static OPENSSL_LIBS="libcrypto32MD.lib libssl32MD.lib" OPENSSL_LIBS_DEBUG="libcrypto32MDd.lib libssl32MDd.lib" OPENSSL_LIBS_RELEASE="libcrypto32MD.lib libssl32MD.lib"
```

But i always got in the output `Checking for OpenSSL... no`

and

```
Qt Network:
getifaddrs() ........................... no
IPv6 ifname ............................ no
libproxy ............................... no
OpenSSL ................................ no
  Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ no
DTLS ................................... no
SCTP ................................... no
Use system proxies ..................... yes
```

And this is the list of files in `E:\Qt\OpenSSL-Win32_full\lib\VC\static` dir

[image]

Why i am facing this ?